# Qt3D 2.0 billboard transformation

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

Billboard transformation was depricated since Qt3D 1.0. Now it is replaced with lookAt transformation.
I have created plane inside Qt3D context. (took it from Qt3D example found  [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drenderer-materials-cpp-example.html)) and added QLookAtTransform to it.
But both:

```
planeEntity->lookAtTransform()->setViewCenter(cameraEntity->position());
```

and

```
planeEntity->lookAtTransform()->setViewVector(cameraEntity->position());
```

give no result. Plane disappear from scene.

Class reference found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-qlookattransform.html) give no explanation of how to use it.

How must QLookAtTransform be used to act like billboard transformation?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at [Gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/150705/109297), the procedure is quite simple once you have the view matrix. The view matrix can be acquired through the appropriate getter of your `Camera` object. If you want to know more, there is also a [link](https://swiftcoder.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/constructing-a-billboard-matrix/) which gives you the detailed derivation.